# Check or Evaluate this Summation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

How do I check or evaluate this summation$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{2(k+1)}{(n+1)(n+2)}=1$$  for $0\le k\le n$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

Comment: See [Faulhaber's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula#Examples).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{2(k+1)}{n+1)(n+2)}=\frac2{(n+1)(n+2)}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k=\frac2{(n+1)(n+2)}\cdot\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}2$$